# Postfix - Use Address Rewriting to add specific recipient to all mail - can't use always_bcc

Tags: postfix

I am setting up a Postfix relay for one purpose - to add a specific email recipient to all emails being relayed through this server.

I thought that I could use always_bcc, which worked, but the bcc recipient can't see the original recipient of the email.  (If they look at the email headers they can find the original recipient but not from the regular mail view in the Office 365 web client).

I was hoping that I could use some sort of recipient address rewriting in Postfix:
*@*.*       ---> *@*.*,monitor@example.com

The goal of this would be to allow the relayed mail to both go to the original recipient but also to be delivered to monitor@example.com.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I certainly appreciate the help!

Dave

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? `https://blog.sys4.de/postfix-gateway-virtual-bcc-multiplicator-en.html`

Comment: It seems to me that the problem with this is that there are no wildcards.  You have to specific each recipient one at a time.  I would like to be able to have a mail relay setup so that *any* recipient can be emailed with a copy of the email going to a fixed email address.  And the catch is that the user of the fixed email address should be able to see the original recipients's email address.  The problem with the always_bcc is that the bcc recipient can't see the original recipient.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This seemed to work for me:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this seemed to work for me (from [Add email recipient in header in Postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/763632/add-email-recipient-in-header-in-postfix)):

```
# main.cf
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/add_original_rcpt.pcre

# cat add_original_rcpt.pcre
/^To:(\s)?(.*)$/ PREPEND X-Original-To: $2
```